# Searching for strings in one txt file in another txt file

Tags: python, string, file, search, txt

Here I just want to search for the keyword in the domain file without doing anything on the files. There is one key and one domain in each line. Please consider performance as there is a lot of data.

My code:

```
def search_keyword_domain():
    # here I just want to search for the keyword in the domain file without doing anything on the files.
    # There is one key and one domain in each line.
    # Please consider performance as there is a lot of data
    
    with open("result.txt", "a") as result:
        result.writelines(line)


def search_keyword():
    with open('domains.txt', 'r') as d:
        for line in d:
            line.strip()
        d.close()

    with open('keywords.txt', 'r') as f:
        for line in f:
            line = line.strip()
            search_keyword_domain(line)
        f.close()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    search_keyword()
```

EXAMPLE:

`strings.txt`: Note: There are 180 keywords.

```
google
messi
apple
```

`domains.txt`: Note: There are 280 million domains.

```
google.com
ronaldovsmess.com
anapple.com
```

Comment: could you please add a little sample of your `domain.txt` and `string.txt` file? what do you exactly mean by "search for each of the keywords in the domains.txt file and **see the results as output**"? what do you want to see, just True and False if existent ? just printed or saved somewhere as new file?

Comment: @Rabinzel I have added the sample file example. do not forget that each of them is in a row.

Comment: thanks. I guess the two context manager should be intended in the function `search_keyword_domain()`, can you double check that ?

Comment: did you like any of the two given answers? Please consider accepting/upvoting one of them

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Few things first:

- No need to have several functions like this. What you could do to make things a bit more general, create a main func with all functions as input arguments.
- If you are using a context manager you don't need to close the file manually, the context manager does that for you
- you don't want to loop through your domain file and call in every itertion the func `search_keyword_domain(line)` where you open the result file, append data and close the file again. Better to collect data, open the file once, write all data to it before it gets closed.
- the first part of your func `search_keyword()` where you open `domain.txt` does nothing... like this, it is useless. You just loop through it once without saving any information or doing something in the loop.
  Here is my solution:

As input I used
`keywords.txt`:

```
google
messi
apple
bus
weather
```

`domain.txt`:

```
google.com
ronaldovsmessi.com
anapple.com
twitter.com
weather.com
youtube.com
```

```py
def search_matching_domains(keywords_file, domain_file, result_file):
    with open(keywords_file, 'r') as f:
        keywords = f.read().splitlines() #keywords is a list with all keywords

    with open(domain_file, 'r') as g: 
        result = [] #collect all matching domains in this list
        for line in g:
            # if any keyword matches the current domain, append the domain
            if any(keyword in line.strip() for keyword in keywords):
                result.append(line)

    with open(result_file, 'w') as h:
        h.write(''.join(result))
        
search_matching_domains('keywords.txt', 'domains.txt', 'result.txt')
```

output in `results.txt`:

```
google.com
ronaldovsmessi.com
anapple.com
weather.com
```

**EDIT**
Some performance tests:

```py
#moved this part out of the functions as it has nothing to do with it
with open('000_keywords.txt', 'r') as f:
    keywords = f.read().splitlines() #keywords is a list with all keywords

def write_list_to_file(keywords, domain_file, result_file):
    with open(domain_file, 'r') as g: 
        result = [] #collect all matching domains in this list
        for line in g:
            # if any keyword matches the current domain, append the domain
            if any(keyword in line.strip() for keyword in keywords):
                result.append(line)

    with open(result_file, 'w') as h:
        h.write(''.join(result))
        
def append_each_loop(keywords, domain_file, result_file):
    with open(domain_file, 'r') as g, open(result_file, 'a+') as h:
        for line in g:
            if any(keyword in line.strip() for keyword in keywords):
                h.write(line)
```

Here are the results (both files didn't exist before I ran the test)

```py
%timeit write_list_to_file(keywords, '000_domains.txt', '000_result.txt')
# 616 µs ± 64.1 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1,000 loops each)

%timeit append_each_loop(keywords, '000_domains.txt', '001_result.txt')
# 6.46 ms ± 137 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
```

Appending everything to a list and write it to the file in the end is faster. I get your point, and I did my version for no special reason as I can't explain why this is faster than what you suggested.

Comment: I would just like to ask. wouldn't it be more efficient to write every incoming result in `for` loop at the same time instead of `appending` the results to the result list?

Comment: Definitely not like in your version because there the file gets opened and closed in every loop. but in the other case i dont know. I'll run some performance test to see if it is fast to write one list at the end or open the file in the beginning and append in each loop to it

Comment: I think it will be a loss of performance to take a listen member and write it down. I find it more reasonable to write every result that comes out with the code that you have written to the file simultaneously.

Answer (score 0):

Modifying your code:

```
import re
import csv

domains = ['']

# convert csv file to txt
txt_file = "./domains.txt"
csv_file = "1.csv"

with open(txt_file, "w") as my_output_file:
    with open(csv_file, "r") as my_input_file:
        [my_output_file.write(" ".join(row) + '\n') for row in csv.reader(my_input_file)]
    my_output_file.close()

def search_keyword_domain(line):
    matching_domains = []
    for x in domains:
        if re.search(line, x):
            matching_domains.append(x)
    print(matching_domains)

def search_keyword():
    with open('domains.txt', 'r') as d:
        for line in d:
            line = line.strip()
            domains.append(line)
        d.close()
    
    with open('keywords.txt', 'r') as f:
        for line in f:
            line = line.strip()
            search_keyword_domain(line)
        f.close()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    search_keyword()
```

If you only want to search and plan on using the results for another csv file then you don't have to convert the csv file to text. The results are mostly the same and `search_keyword_domain` function returns a list you can use to make a new csv file.

**EDIT**

To fix the memory issue I used a generator for the domains file.

I also created two functions to test what @Rabinzel said about the operation speed of writing directly to the result file vs appending to a list before writing. My keywords.txt file has only 6 keywords while my domains.txt file has 50,000 lines for testing.

```
def search_keyword_tofile():
    with open('keywords.txt', 'r') as key_file, open('domains.txt', 'r') as domain_file, open('result.txt', 'a') as result:
        keys = [key_line.strip() for key_line in key_file]
        domains = (domain_line.strip() for domain_line in domain_file)
        for domain_line in domains:
            for key_line in keys:
                if re.search(key_line, domain_line):
                    result.write(domain_line)
        result.close()  
        domain_file.close() 
        key_file.close()

def search_keyword_tolist():
    matching_domains = []
    with open('keywords.txt', 'r') as key_file, open('domains.txt', 'r') as domain_file:

        keys = [key_line.strip() for key_line in key_file]
        domains = (domain_line.strip() for domain_line in domain_file)
        for domain_line in domains:
            for key_line in keys:
                if re.search(key_line, domain_line):
                    matching_domains.append(domain_line)    
        domain_file.close() 
        key_file.close()
    
    with open('result.txt', 'a') as result:
        result.write('\n'.join(matching_domains))
        result.close()
```

As for the the result of the code:

```
%timeit -n 100 search_keyword_tofile()
# 333 ms ± 1.57 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)

%timeit -n 100 search_keyword_tofile()
# 332 ms ± 838 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
```

As you can see there is negligible difference in performance, this is actually a second run and the search_keyword_tofile function was worse on the first run.

I also attempted to reduce the length of the code but lost a bit of performance:

```
def search_keyword_tolist():
    with open('keywords.txt', 'r') as key_file, open('domains.txt', 'r') as domain_file, open('result.txt', 'a') as result:
        keys = [key_line.strip() for key_line in key_file]
        matching_domains = [domain_line for domain_line in domain_file for key_line in keys if re.search(key_line, domain_line.strip())]
        result.write('\n'.join(matching_domains))
        result.close()  
        domain_file.close() 
        key_file.close()
```

performance results:

```
%timeit -n 100 search_keyword_tolist()
# 364 ms ± 879 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
```

considering the size of your dataset you might not want to do this if your in a rush.

I would also advice writing directly to the file if there is a possibility of having many lines matching the keywords.

Comment: happened since memory swells too much. How do I optimize this I just want to read it and write the matching results to a file.

Comment: why didnt you say that in your question? please add all information that is needed

Comment: you can use the snippet from Alexander above, simply add functionality to write to another file. Just to confirm, you do understand his code?

Comment: @Uyonoh his code also inflates memory. i just need to read it line by line and look for the keyword in it.

Comment: @Rabinzel I edite, can you check?. I'm sorry